# Why is the parent scroll event getting triggered , when scrolling inside child,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-bubbling

From what I know scroll event doesn't get bubbled to the parent and only bubbles document itself then why parent scroll event is getting fired,

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const refParent = useRef(null);
  const refChild = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleParent() {
      console.log("Parent");
    }
    function handleChild() {
      console.log("Child");
    }
    if (refParent && refChild) {
      refParent.current.addEventListener("mousewheel", handleParent);
      refChild.current.addEventListener("mousewheel", handleChild);
    }
    return () => {
      refParent.current.removeEventListener("mousewheel", handleParent);
      refChild.current.removeEventListener("mousewheel", handleChild);
    };
  });
  return (
    <div
      style={{ width: "400px", height: "200px", background: "red" }}
      ref={refParent}
    >
      <div
        style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px", overflow: "auto" }}
        ref={refChild}
      >
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas, dolorum
        nisi, debitis optio magnam perferendis similique delectus incidunt alias
        eum dignissimos est quis assumenda doloribus rem deserunt tempora eos
        reiciendis!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Quas, dolorum nisi, debitis optio magnam perferendis similique delectus
        incidunt alias eum dignissimos est quis assumenda doloribus rem deserunt
        tempora eos reiciendis! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Quas, dolorum nisi, debitis optio magnam perferendis
        similique delectus incidunt alias eum dignissimos est quis assumenda
        doloribus rem deserunt tempora eos reiciendis!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas, dolorum nisi, debitis optio magnam
        perferendis similique delectus incidunt alias eum dignissimos est quis
        assumenda doloribus rem deserunt tempora eos reiciendis!
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is the live example https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-silence-lxi1jb?file=/src/App.js

Thanks

Comment: Because while scrolling inside child, sometime you will arrive to the end of the child's scroll, then, the parent scroll event gets triggered. It's the "normal" HTML behavior.

Comment: @ericmp Yep. On top of that the only reason the parent scroll moves a bit in the first place is cos codesandbox looks like has an extra bit of padding. Probably wouldnt happen in reality as the parent wouldn't have a scroll bar anyway.

Comment: @ericmp that is not the case here tho it is even getting triggered when I am scrolling from start to the middle and to the end alternatively, kindly check out the live demo along with its console for more information

Comment: Hmm yep youre right. I see the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are using the `mousewheel` event and not the `scroll` event. The `mousewheel` event will bubble and is just saying did the user issue a command to their machine to *attempt* a scroll. It's like `onClick` but for the mouse wheel.

You meant to use the `scroll` event which means "did this frame move scroll position".

Comment: To prevent this event bubble, you can use `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Yeh. Depends on if he wants to know when the div did actually scroll (vast majority of cases) or if some reason he wants to always detect scrollwheel events (less likely, few use cases for this).

Comment: thanks man, but i am restricted to use mousewheel since I want to create an effect which is when user scroll vertically programmatically it should get horizontally scrolled and that was working with mousewheel and its not working with scroll as you mentioned the reason for the same in you solution, so you have any alternative for that ?

Comment: something like this https://mylesnguyen.com/ but along with this I also have a vertical scroll in one of those slides which I want to keep the way they are

Comment: Gotcha yes you are one of the special cases! In this case, you could just stop propogation on the even in the child container. `e.stopPropagation()`. The mousewheel events are bubbled, which is what youre seeing.